# Insert values into identity column manually and automatically in one query

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2016

I have a table in SQL Server with identity column.

I need to insert N+M rows into it. For N rows, I need manually to insert the value of identity column. For other M rows, the value for identity column should be auto-generated.

Each row of input data has an attribute (bit column) which defines whether value should be auto-generated or created manually.

I **can** achieve it with two separate INSERT statements - one with SET IDENTITY_INSERT ON for N rows, and another one with IDENTITY_INSERT OFF for M rows.

Question: **is it possible to achieve it with ONE single INSERT statement** , e.g. by using some built-in function that generates the values for identity column?

Comment: What version of SQL Server do you use? SQL Server 2012+ has `SEQUENCE`.

Comment: I use SQL 2016 SP1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Some simulation identity insertion:

```
CREATE TABLE #Test (Id int IDENTITY(1,1) PRIMARY KEY, Value int)

INSERT INTO #Test 
VALUES
(100),
(200)

SELECT *
FROM #Test AS t

DECLARE @Temp TABLE (Id int, Value int, SetId bit)
INSERT INTO @Temp 
VALUES
(-1, 1,1),
(-2, 2,1),
(-1, 33,0),
(-1, 44,0)

SET IDENTITY_INSERT #Test ON

INSERT INTO #Test 
(Id, Value)
SELECT
    CASE(t.SetId)
        WHEN 1 THEN t.Id --just insert new Id
        WHEN 0 THEN 
            IDENT_CURRENT('#Test') --get last identity value
            + ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY t.Id) --simulate identity +1
            - (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM @Temp AS t2 WHERE t2.SetId = 1) --skip inserted rows with Id
            + 1
    END,
    t.[Value]
FROM @Temp AS t

SET IDENTITY_INSERT #Test OFF

SELECT *
FROM #Test AS t

DROP TABLE #Test
```

Comment: Thanks, Backs! Do you think this method will perform better than two separate INSERTs? From time to time, the target and source tables may contain millions rows. Does IDENT_CURRENT() is the same function that SQL engine calls for every inserted row when identity column is being auto-generated?

Comment: @Anton i think, 2 separate inserts are much better. You'll get simpler code that easy to maintaince. `IDENT_CURRENT` returns last generated identity for table: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175098.aspx

Comment: Keep in mind, that if you use `IDENT_CURRENT` you'll have problems if there is a chance that two separate processes would try to insert the values at the same time. Two separate `INSERTs` would always work correctly.

Comment: Having said that, if you use SQL Server 2012+, you can use `SEQUENCE` instead of `IDENTITY` and [`NEXT VALUE FOR`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff878370.aspx) would work correctly in multi-user environment.

Comment: More information: priority for me is performance. There is no way that some other process adds a row into the table. Also manually generated values for identity column are always less than max identity

Comment: @Anton 2 inserts are better in perfomance, i think. In my solution where is window function `ROW_NUMBER`, subquery with `COUNT`. If you have many rows, it can be a problem. Wrap 2 inserts with transaction and it's enough

Comment: Ok, thanks Backs for your help. Also tried SEQUENCE (many thanks to Vladimir!) - works fine and it's fast if CACHE parameter is high enough. For one million inserted rows, with NEXT VALUE FOR, it showed same execution time as with IDENTITY(1,1).

Comment: @Anton, yes Vladimir's conment is very usefull. Glad to help!

Comment: I can't use NEXT VALUE FOR  in CASE END statement (limitation of sql server). And in other conditional statements like ISNULL, IIF,...  as well. :(